# Porting an OOP ObserverPattern to Rust

Tags: rust

I am porting an SDK from Java&Golang to Rust. These SDKs work auto-generating boilerplate code like this using templates (In java using OOP and in Golang using Reflection):

```
trait RPC {
  fn decode(&self, frame: &Frame) -> ();
  fn execute(&self) -> ();
}
struct MyRPC{
  decoded: String
}
impl MyRPC for RPC{
  //default implementations of decode and execute methods.
}
```

I would like that my user could do something like this so the only code that they need to write is the business logic:

```
include("autogeneratedCode")
impl MyRPC{
  fn execute(&self){
     //Do something with &self.decoded
  }
}
```

`execute()` function should be called using an observer pattern:

```
let subscribers: HashMap<String, Box<dyn RPC>>    
pub fn publish(&self, frame: &Frame) -> () {
  for subscriber in self.subscribers.iter() {
     let mut cloned_subscriber = subscriber.1.clone();  // <<1
     cloned_subscriber.parse(frame);  // <<2
     cloned_subscriber.execute(); // <<3
  }
}
```

I'm not able to make this code work in Rust having this problems:

1. `variable does not need to be mutable Note:` #[warn(unused_mut)]`on by default Help: remove this`mut`.` I guess the problem is that subscriber.1.clone() is a `Box<dyn &RPC>` and being a reference we should not mutate it?
2. `cannot borrow` **cloned_subscriber`as mutable, as it is behind a`&`reference [E0596]`cloned_subscriber`is a`& `reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable.`
3. This is executing the default implementation and not the one in MyRPC written by the SDK user.

I feel that I am trying to force Rust to work object oriented, and maybe that is the problem. Should I use a more Rusty approach? I really like our current Golang/Java implementations using this "pattern" since the user only need to write the `execute()` function and all the underling machinery works, but maybe this won't be an option in Rust.

Comment: Is `subscribers` a global variable? If so, that's where trouble starts. How are you going to alter that?

Comment: Tip: You can skip the `-> ()` part, it's implied.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `clone()` your RPC entry? That could be expensive. If you need to share references, you probably need `Rc` or `Arc`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the pattern you might need here is not slinging around `trait` implementations, but instead perhaps a closure instead if al you're doing is calling a function at the end of the day. The `parse`/`execute` thing implies some kind of internal state in the RPC call, which means either interior mutability issues, or mutable reference headaches.

Comment: The subscribers are not global. It is member of the struct Publisher. I put it there just to give an example of the type of subscribers.